# How to wait for translated text to appear in DeepL.com

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

After entering original text in [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator), it takes 1-2 sec for translated text to appear.

I'm unable to get translated text with `TimeoutException`.

I've tried to Synchronize using:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...
# ...
# ...

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='target-dummydiv']"), "\r\n"))
translatedText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='target-dummydiv']").text
```

Checking for non-empty translated text:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(self.IsTranslatedTextNotEmpty)
translatedText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='target-dummydiv']").text

def IsTranslatedTextNotEmpty(self, driver: WebDriver):
    translatedText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='target-dummydiv']").text
    return len(translatedText) > 0
```

doesn't work.

*Note*: Synchronization using `time.sleep(5)` works.

Comment: Try printing out that elements text and see what value you get first.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Langth 0 empty text

Comment: Does your string equal that. Wouldn’t it wait 0s.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan It contains translated text. Please see above code for checking non-empty translated text.

Comment: there is a free API with a p/m character limit.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, API is a solution. For production code, I'll go for API. This project was a tutorial I was practicing which instructor had solved using Selenium & `time.sleep()`.